# How to find and set an HTML-Select option element using its data attribute?

Tags: jquery, html-select

I have the following HTML:

```
<select name="1028071" class="LC" id="1028071" style="width: 100%;">
    <option selected="selected" value="-1">[Please select a value]</option>
    <option value="10604534" data-uid="154b2706-505e-401c-a066-a37a1889e3be">[Other]</option>
    <option value="10604535" data-uid="25070b3b-8215-440b-b3cf-c6cf52f01efc">Reason 1</option>
    <option value="10604536" data-uid="fd3394ea-a7e8-45e8-8385-71dee98238ff">Reason 2</option>
</select>
```

I am trying to pre-select `[Other]`. Both `value` and the text are variables. The only fixed value across environments is the `data-uid`.

I tried the following but it is not working:

```
var other = $(formalRequestReasonFieldId).find("option").filter(function() {
    return $(this).data('uid') == '154b2706-505e-401c-a066-a37a1889e3be';
});

alert(other.text()); // returns blank text
other.attr('selected', true); // does not work, no errors
```

Comment: `$('option[data-uid="154b2706-505e-401c-a066-a37a1889e3be"]')`

Comment: What you have should work fine: https://jsfiddle.net/ffw5quqr/. Have you checked the console to ensure there are no errors, and the value of the `uid` you're searching for is what you expect it to be?

Comment: It should work, unless you are changing the `uid` value using the `data` api

Comment: @downvoter: care to comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If **formalRequestReasonFieldId** is the Select tag ID :

```
var other = $('#'+formalRequestReasonFieldId).find('option[data-uid="154b2706-505e-401c-a066-a37a1889e3be"]');

//Other Text
var text = other.text();

//Select It
other.prop("selected", true);
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6opqnxhy/

Comment: The missing part is '#'.. Thanks. Just forgot to add it to the `formalRequestReasonFieldId` variable.